# Is the 'updateMany' function of mongodb deprecated?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

```
db.movieDetails.updateMany({
    "tomato.consensus": null,
    "imdb.votes":{$lt:10000},
    "year":{$gte:2010,$lte:2013}},
    {
       $unset:{"tomato.consensus":""
    }
})
```

When I typed the command above in the `mongo` shell, I received an error that stated that `updateMany` was not a valid function.

> TypeError: Property 'updateMany' of object video.movieDetails is not a function at (shell):1:17

I checked the documentation and `updateMany` is listed a valid function. I would like to know why I received the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `updateMany` command has not been deprecated. You'll find the documentation for the command here: [db.collection.updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany).

You were unable to use the command because it was introduced in the `3.2` version of MongoDB. You need to install the `3.2` version to use the `updateMany` command.

Comment: Thanks, i was using 3.0.2 :(

Comment: From my reading of the docs `update` using the `multi` flag should do the same thing as `updateMany`. Is this true?

Comment: @matth if you are using monogdb 2.2 then 
db.test.update({foo: "bar"}, {$set: {test: "success!"}}, {multi: true})

Comment: @gnerkus my MongoDB version: 3.2.15 it works in shell but when i try to call from node then it shows updateMany is not a function

as it works by giving multi true but can i do by the updateMany?

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me

```
 db.collection.update({},{$set:{,is_expired:false}},{multi:true})
```